# In ASP.NET is it possible to store class files in a folder not under app_code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web, iis

My searching skills seem to be failing me on this one. It is a simple question;

In ASP.NET is it possible to store class files in a folder not under app_code?

What I am trying to accomplish is create class files which when added (or modified) to the web site will not cause the web site to restart. Anything under App_code or in the bin folder causes a restart. We are not using .NET for the presentation layer.

My reason is simple, we make changes somewhat regularly, and I do not want to wait until a specific time to add/change a feature. These are 24 hour websites and there is no great time to restart them.

Edit:

I am using FluorineFX to access the middle tier. I created a folder called "ProdCode" from the root of the application. When I try to access the NameSpace ProdeCode, class Employee_Calendar method getEvents. I get the error "Failed to locate the requested  type ProdCode.Employee_Calendar"

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: To accomplish the 24/7 uptime that you want, you're looking at the wrong thing. The proper way to accomplish that is to have multiple running instances of your service, red/green deployments, healthchecks etc.

Comment: @David I edited the question with the error.

Comment: Update bin or App_Code won't restart cause IIS restarting. IIS recycle the application pool only when application pool configuration has been changed or memory/request limit exceeeded. Please go to event viewer system log and check the reason for IIS app pool recycling first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the goal of a non-restart is huge different, and HUGE separate from that of being able to place code modules, or class modules in some other folder.

When you build the project, most of the modules (and class ones) are crunched down to a single .dll anyway.

So, while you are free to add new folders and inside of those folders add new code/class modules? That may not well eliminate the need for the site to re-load, or in fact the site to re-compile the code again.

All of the app_code, and any other code module will crank out and result in a single .dll file. So, I don't see how you going to gain, or win anything new here.

What you could perhaps do is build some classes outside of the project, compile them, and then set a reference to the external code (and class) modules in the other project. That would suggest a external .dll. This would work during debugging, but an "il-merge" usealy occurs when publishing as non debug, and thus the gazillion .dll's are merged into one.

So, separate out code - great idea.
Adding code to additional folders - sure - no problem (do right click on the given class, or code module and make SURE the build action is compile - this is a default for app code - for other folders I can't remember. You need to check this.

so, up to this point? Hey, all great.

But, to save site re-compile time? No, this where train is flying off a big broken bridge, and the whole she-bang is crashing up in a HUGE ball of flames.

You might be able to same some time during debugging, but those included module are pulled into the "main" .dll (same name as your applcation). Go check the "bin" folder now - you not see the app_code .dll's but only one main .dll with the name of your project.

Such re-compile time is useally rather fast for the site to re-load. I you are just changing markup, then fine. But the idea that you want to include compiled code, and attempting to avoid a re-load? No I would not consider this - even if you could! I mean, how many times have you seen code fail or NOT take even after a publish and FORGETTING to re-start the web server? Those .dll's are often loaded into memory, locked and 100+ more issues exist. I many a time lost half a day because my .dll's did not take (due to me not re-starting the web server). there is pain and then there is this kind of "pain" in which parts of your application don't load. I just can't imagine the risk vs rewards in trying to save some time??? - I must be missing something here?

Comment: I do not compile my site. I execute native vb code. If I want/need a .dll I create and compile it separately. The app_code folder contains a few .vb files, but in the future I will be creating one vb file per "page."

Comment: You can't execute vb code until it is compiled - end of story. If you are compiling the code outside of VS (command line) then fine, but in ALL cases your code HAS to be compiled to run. Software ONLY works this way - so yes, you ARE compiling the code.  When you use web published then "il-merge" comes into play. So, sure, you can execute separate compile commands, but you making more work then needed.  And if you are cobbling together a system in which YOU execute separate compile commands then you are free to do so.  You can thus set path names for .dll's, or you can even use LoadLibrary.

Comment: Yes you are correct source code cannot execute. However it is possible, and I run a number of websites where I place ".vb" files in the app_code tree and allow IIS to compile the code for me rather than precompiling the code to DLLs. and putting the DLLs in APP_CODE or bin.